# Rethrowing new exception with same message causes garbage output. Why?

Tags: c++, exception, c-strings

I want to catch an exception to further specify the error message, then throw a new exception with that extended message. However, that causes garbage output. Why?

Here's an MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>

class myError : public std::exception
{
private:
    std::string m_error;

public:
    explicit myError( const std::string& error ) :
        m_error { error }
    {}
    explicit myError( const char* error ) :
        m_error { error }
    {} 

    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        //return m_error.c_str();
        return ("My error: " + m_error).c_str();
    }
};


int main()
{
    try{
        try{
            throw myError ( "Error message" );
        } catch ( const std::exception& e ) {
            throw myError( e.what() );
        }
    } catch ( const std::exception& e ) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the output to be "My error: My error: Error message", but instead, it's a short sequence of random characters, presumably until a `\0` is hit.

If I do not add a message inside `myError::what()` (i.e. the line that's commented out), then the output is simply "Error message", so everything works as expected.
Why is that happening?

I'm running gcc 8.1.0 on Windows, with x86_64-posix-seh-rev0 as the install options.

And I'm somewhat aware of nested_exception and that I'm losing some information on the trace etc.

EDIT: As a workaround, adding the message "My error" inside the constructor produces the expected output:

```
    explicit myError( const std::string& error ) :
        m_error { "My error: " + error }
    {}
    explicit myError( const char* error ) :
        m_error { "My error: " + std::string{ error } }
    {}

    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return m_error.c_str();
    }
```

So something seems to be wrong with `return ("My error: " + m_error).c_str();`.

Comment: `"My error: " + m_error` is a temporary object. It'll be freed after that function. It's UB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In:

```
return ("My error: " + m_error).c_str();
```

... `c_str()` returns a pointer to the internal buffer of the temporary string created by the concatenation. This string's lifetime ends immediately after the `return` statement, making the returned pointer dangling and its use undefined.

Comment: Right.. Rather obvious now. I know why I've avoided C-style strings and raw pointers in all of my code :D